# How to debug ios app that is built from "Ionic cordova add platform ios"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an IOS build of my app that terminates the app whenever I open a camera/barcode scanner. **I like to know what are ways I can to debug this issue** ?

*For Android I used to connect the device through USB and open device inspector in Chrome.*

Thank you.

Comment: Refer to: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/#ios-debugging

Comment: Thanks Marius, will definitely try this.